# Is it possible to interrupt evaluation of an expression

Tags: c, interrupt, reentrancy

Consider the following piece of code.

```
#‎include‬ <stdio.h>

void f(int *x, int *y)
{
    (*x)++;
    (*y)++;
}

int main()
{
    int x=5, y=5;

    f(&x, &y);

return 0;
}
```

I know that the function f is not reentrant. One of the stupid things I am thinking is to do (*x)++ + (*y)++ in one line and discard the sum. I wonder that multiple assembly instructions will be generated for evaluation of this expression. Will the interrupt be served in between evaluation of expression?

Comment: What do you mean by "interrupt"? Can you please elaborate? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Yes it can. But please, for the love of the programming Gods, please don't do what you have suggested. It's much better to write clear code than "clever" code.

Comment: Thanks Alan Au. I know it is stupid to do. What kind of operation are guaranteed to be atomic in C? I think it is a separate question but still for maintaining the context I am asking here.

Comment: @user902384: The C standard says nothing about interrupts, even less about schedulers, and not to even talk about operating systems. Thus, the C standard does not mandate any single operation to be "atomic", as that's not standard/portable terminology.

Comment: One of the clever ways I know is put a sigmask before modification and then reset the sigmask once changes are done.

Comment: @user902384: That won't stop the scheduler/kernel from preempting your process, neither other threads from calling your function. Anyway, in CS, `clever` is synonym for `stupid micro/premature optimization`.

Comment: How do I make my function f reentrant then?

Comment: @user902384 The current process being interrupted won't change the result of the execution (unless there is some modified global state in the interim that affects such; but there is none in this case).

Comment: @user2864740 I understand it much better now.

Comment: @user902384 What do you mean by "interrupt"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get anything atomic with that...

```
c.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <f>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 89 7d f8             mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
   8:   48 89 75 f0             mov    %rsi,-0x10(%rbp)
   c:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   10:  8b 00                   mov    (%rax),%eax
   12:  8d 50 01                lea    0x1(%rax),%edx
   15:  48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   19:  89 10                   mov    %edx,(%rax)
   1b:  48 8b 45 f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
   1f:  8b 00                   mov    (%rax),%eax
   21:  8d 50 01                lea    0x1(%rax),%edx
   24:  48 8b 45 f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
   28:  89 10                   mov    %edx,(%rax)
   2a:  5d                      pop    %rbp
   2b:  c3                      retq
```

And it gets a lot better with `-O2`, but still it's not atomic.

```
c.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <f>:
   0:   83 07 01                addl   $0x1,(%rdi)
   3:   83 06 01                addl   $0x1,(%rsi)
   6:   c3                      retq
```

And, at least for GCC, the *exact same code* is generated for `(*x)++ + (*y++)`. Anyway, may you elaborate a little bit on your question? You're being too broad and this code *is* reentrant as long as `x` and `y` are not the same on different entries. Otherwise, you should give us more details about you're intending.

**Edit**: It's (apparently, unless there's some hidden black magic...) impossible to do such a thing atomically on a x86(-64) architecture. Anyway, it's non-portable to consider an operation "atomic" if it is done in a single instruction. That's specific to x86(-64) CPUs.

Comment: No the function f in original form is not reentrant. If interrupt is served after increment of x then y will not be increased. Another call to f from main is disturbed.

Comment: @user902384: It *is* reentrant as long as its not called with the same argument(s) by other thread. And what's the problem with `y` not being incremented inmediately? After the OS resumes the task, it will be; no "perturbation" occurs.

Comment: @user902384: p.d: Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)), just to be sure we have the same definition of "reentrancy".

Comment: Thanks for your insightful explanation. I am not worried about y being incremented immediately. I do not know whether after interrupt is served it will resume the execution of f? I am sorry for not studying in detail about interrupts. Is it guaranteed that execution will resume at the same place where it was interrupted? Can you please give a reference?

Comment: I will accept your answer because it makes sense to me that it is reentrant as long as it is not called with same arguments. That means programming discipline is often more valuable than it is deemed.

Comment: @user902384: I can give you *a lot* of references for that :). [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch), [2 (pretty advanced...)](http://wiki.osdev.org/Context_Switching), [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt), [4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_request_(PC_architecture)). Tell me if you need more info. After all, *a lot* of programs would just crash if the OS allowed such a thing to happen, no?

Comment: Hehe :P yes I am just very doubtful.